# Pentaho MDX roles

Tags: pentaho, mondrian

I try to create some restriction in pentaho jpivot
1. i have 2 users (user1 - role1 and user2 - role2)
2. i have a pivot with this values

```
 store | owner | sales
 ---------------------
 s1    | user1 | 1235
       | user2 | 2684
 s2    | user1 | 1628
       | user2 | 1002
 s3    | user1 | 1111
       | user2 | 1596
...
```

my schema look like this one:

```
<Schema name="asimov1">
  <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="owner" name="owner">
   <Hierarchy name="owner" visible="true" hasAll="false" primaryKey="owner" primaryKeyTable="storeTable">
     <Level name="owner" visible="true" table="storeTable" column="owner" uniqueMembers="false">
     </Level>
   </Hierarchy>
 </Dimension>
 <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="store1" name="store1">
  <Hierarchy name="store1" visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="store1" primaryKeyTable="storeTable">
     <Level name="store1" visible="true" table="storeTable" column="store1" uniqueMembers="false">
     </Level>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
<Cube name="asimov1" caption="asimov1" visible="true" description="asimov1"  cache="true" enabled="true">
  <Table name="storeTable">
  </Table>
  <DimensionUsage source="store1" name="store1" visible="true" foreignKey="store1">
  </DimensionUsage>
  <DimensionUsage source="owner" name="owner" visible="true" foreignKey="owner">
  </DimensionUsage>
  <Measure name="sales" column="sales" formatString="#" aggregator="sum">
  </Measure>

 </Cube>
</Schema>
```

my select:

```
select NON EMPTY Crossjoin({[owner].[owner].Members}, {[Measures].[sales]}) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {[store].[store].Members} ON ROWS
from [role_test]
```

I want when i login as user1 to see just user1 values and so for user2.

I made this using xaction who add a where clause, but user1 stil can see values of user2 if access the jpivot OLAP navigator.

I added visible="false" to dimension owner, but no effect.
I made roles with no effect.

```
<Role name="user1">
<SchemaGrant access="none">
  <CubeGrant cube="asimov1" access="all">
    <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="owner" topLevel="owner" bottomLevel="owner" access="custom">
      <MemberGrant member="[owner].[user1]" access="all">
      </MemberGrant>
      <MemberGrant member="[owner].[user2]" access="none">
      </MemberGrant>
    </HierarchyGrant>
  </CubeGrant>
</SchemaGrant>
```

....

That's all, so please gime some guidance.

Best regards,
dga

Answer (score 0):

All was good, except this:

Before use roles must uncomment this line in **biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/pentahoObjects.spring.xml**

```
<bean id="Mondrian-UserRoleMapper" 
    name="Mondrian-One-To-One-UserRoleMapper"  
    class="org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.mondrian.mapper.MondrianOneToOneUserRoleListMapper" 
    scope="singleton" />
```

Comment: FYI in 7.1 that is now the default, and the documentation on other role mappers can be found here: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0N0/020/080/010